# Excel- Generate a list from single cell input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My question is basically how can you generate a list in Excel based on a single cell input?

For example, the user types 10 then replaces it with 20 and then 30 etc, is it possible to generate a list like:
10
20
30
etc

EDIT: As an additional requirement, is it possible it adjust the code, or provide an additional code to allow additional instances of this? For example, generate an additional list for a 2nd or 3rd etc single cell input.

Thanks for the help!
Alistair

Answer (score 2):

This example monitors user changes to cell **A1**
The list is built in column **B** starting in cell **B2**

Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RR As Range, N As Long, v As Variant
    Set RR = Intersect(Target, Range("A1"))
    If RR Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Range("A1").Text
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B" & N).Value = v
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it worked perfectly.

If I needed to do this multiple times on the same worksheet (ie create another list from a different input cell), can I just duplicate the macro (apart from obviously changing cell reference) or will I need to change a line in there?

Comment: @Alistair  Update your requirements and I'll update the code!

Comment: I have edited and updated my original post, I assume that is what you meant by requirements. Thanks!

Comment: hi there, just wondering if you had a chance to look at the updated requirements? Would love to know if you had a possible solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll check on it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1 put 10, in A2 put =A1+$A$1 
Pull the cell A2 down.
I have [uploaded the solution](http://www.filedropper.com/excel_1).

Comment: Hi Davidenko, 
Thanks for your reply. I may not have provided the best example, instead of adding the previous cell I would like the list to contain the unique number that is input each time.

For example, if the user types 10 then replaces with 9 then 14 then 20 in the single cell, the list should generate as 10 9 14 20.
Hopefully that helps your understanding, let me know if you have any other ideas.