# How to create a list using a single cell input multiple times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example user type 1 then replace with 4 then replace with 21 on cell A1, Then user type 5 then replace with 2 then replace with 32 on cell B1, etc.
And excel will generate something like
this:

```
1  5  etc.

4  2  etc.

21 32 etc.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

General answer, no "turnkey" solution:

First note that you cannot make Excel or any other spreadsheet "put" values in a cell.

Which means that: a cell value can be either:

- something you have manually typed in that cell, or
- the result created by a formula in that cell.

You need a macro for copying values into cells.

---

Which cell to copy the entered value into: Example calculations;

Given e.g. `="B10:G14"` in cell B1 and with something entered in cells `B10 to B14`;

- `=ROWS(INDIRECT(B1))` in B2 tells how many rows the area has -> e.g 5
- `=COLUMNS(INDIRECT(B1))` in B3 tells how many columns the area has -> e.g 6
- `=B2*B3` -> in B4, number of cells in the area -> e.g. 30
- `=COUNTA(INDIRECT(B1))` in B5, how many cells has content -> e.g. 5.
- `=B4-B5` in B6, how many free cells there are -> e.g. 25

The Row and Column inside the area to put the next entered value in:
`=INT((B5+1)/B2)` and `=MOD(B5+1;B2)`

Now, to have this work I recommend creating a simple macro to use these values to copy the value in e.g. A1 to the calculated position. All the above will update automatically as the macro has done its job.

Then create a button using items in the "Developer" tab and make that macro run as you click the button.

As you're at it you might as well create one more macro, that deletes the last value from the table area.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm basing on this https://superuser.com/questions/864394/excel-generate-a-list-from-single-cell-input?answertab=active#tab-top but I cant do it multiple times.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change()` is problematic with entering values, as it runs on ANY change, e.g. a simple `ENTER` in any cell.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions so that I can tweak the program? It will be much appreciated

Comment: Sorry, no. I do not have Excel available, so cannot tryout things. The macro I suggest need not do anything more than using the above to locate the cell and copy the value into it.